# Função click com uma variável de um model

Tags: html, angular

Iae pessoal, tenho um `model` recebendo o valor de uma web api perfeitamente, porém o problema é que eu tenho uma função que preciso pegar o valor do `model` e colocar na função do click como parâmetro e ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 13 in [PegarValores({{pesquisas.Codigo}})] in ng:///AppModule/FormpesquisaComponent.html@37:49
```

Não sei se estou chamando o model da maneira certa, mas vou colocar o código abaixo do model, e do `html` para melhor entendimento do problema:

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="PegarValores({{pesquisas.Codigo}})">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></i>Iniciar
</button>
```

**MODEL**

```
export class Pesquisa {
    public Codigo: number;
    public Id: number;
    public Nome: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No angular dentro do método não precisa dos colchetes.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="PegarValores(pesquisas.Codigo)">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></i>Iniciar
</button>
```

Comment: Pronto, deu certo, obrigado!!